# Getting exceptions when apply .useDelimiter

Tags: java, file, exception, input, java.util.scanner

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUN4I.png)

I have several problems:

1. the contents of the file are not completely displayed, only the
   first line and part two.
2. I tried to replace the parameter in the function .useDelimeter ()
   from "="  to  ", | \n" . I got all the contents of the file, but the
   exception is not lost.
3. I changed from throwExceptions to try-catch, but the result remains
   the same

I don't understand how to correct exceptions.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Code is text. Please post it as such.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is that the input file has new line ending as well which has to be treated as delimiter as well.

Instead of using only "=" as delimiter, do something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Phase_1.txt")).useDelimiter("[=\\r\\n]+");
```

**Explanation:**

useDelimiter() accepts regular expression also. `[=\\r\\n]+` is a regular expression.

`+`: The plus sign indicates one or more occurrences of the preceding element. For example, ab+c matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on, but not "ac".

`[]`: A bracket expression. Matches a single character that is contained within the brackets. For example, [abc] matches "a", "b", or "c".

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Line endings actually depend on the OS. For Windows, it is `\r\n`. For Unix, it is `\n`.

Two `\\` are added to escape `\`. Read more on Escape Sequences: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html.

So, By `[=\\r\\n]+`, we mean that if either `=`, or `\r` or `\n` appears more than once, treat it as one delimiter. So, The following will be treated as one delimiter:

`=, \r, \n, =\r, =\r\r, =\r\n, ==, \r\n, and so on.`

Actually, In your case, the file is like this:

`muffin=bobby=25.0=pug\r\ntiny=eth=22.0=poodle\r\nrex=david=40.0=ab`

By mentioning the above delimiter regular expression, Scanner will treat the following as delimiter.

muffin`=`bobby`=`25.0`=`pug`\r\n`tiny`=`eth`=`22.0`=`poodle`\r\n`rex`=`david`=`40.0`=`ab

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: I'm new to programming and don't understand some things. What are the characters you use in the parentheses ("[=\\r\\n]+") ? I did not quite understand. How it's called I want to read about it.

Comment: @MykhailoVasylenko See the explanation. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You are helped me very much. Thanks

Comment: @MykhailoVasylenko If you feel that the answer really solved your issue, Please accept it as helpful.